# how to Check any 2 checkBox from 4 CheckBoxes?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Good Afternoon Developer,
         this is my content in asp .net, I want the user can check only 2 checkbox,exceeding that alert box should pop up.

```
 <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="q3a" runat="server" Text="Public" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="q3b" runat="server" Text="void" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="q3c" runat="server" Text="protected"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="q3d" runat="server" Text="return" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="submit" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

how can i write javascript for this, i have tried but can't find any way out, Pls help...

Comment: Why don't you use the builtin ASP.NET-Validator Controls? You could use a CustomValidator for this purpose which would also work on clientside with an appropriate [`ClientValidationFunction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop the user the instant they try and select a third option so that only two checked values can ever be submitted and avoid server side validation.

The client side onchange event should be hooked up to a function similar to this;

```
function validationCheck(checkbox) {
  if(checkbox.checked) {
    var count = 0;

    count += document.getElementById('q3a').checked ? 1 : 0;
    count += document.getElementById('q3b').checked ? 1 : 0;
    count += document.getElementById('q3c').checked ? 1 : 0;
    count += document.getElementById('q3d').checked ? 1 : 0;

    if(count > 2) {
      alert('You may only select two options.');
      checkbox.checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

The input should render with `onchange="validationCheck(this);"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JQuery:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {

        var n = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
        if (n > 2) {
            alert('2 are already selected!');
            $(this).attr("checked", false);
        }
    });
```

If you really want to use `JavaScript` try this function:

```
function checkCondition(chkbox) {
    var buttonGroup = document.getElementsByName("group");
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < buttonGroup.length; i++) {
        if (buttonGroup[i].checked) {
            total++;
        }
    }
    if (total > 2) {
        alert('2 are already selected!');
        chkbox.checked =false;
    }
}
```

And also set `onclick="checkCondition(this)"` on your checkboxes and set their `name` attribute to the `group` value for example

Answer (score 0):

agree with @Tim you can just write an on_click function for all checkboxes and then validate there if more then two chekboxes are selected and display error message when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`jQuery`](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=231) to [find all selected checkboxes](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

```
var count = $("input:checked").length;
```

Then you have all you need.

But i would recommend to use the builtin [ASP.NET-Validator Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx). You could use a `CustomValidator` for this purpose which would also work on clientside with an appropriate [`ClientValidationFunction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a client side onclick event for the check box and using jQuery you can check if the check box is checked. You can have a counter that should measure the threshold and then pop up the message if it exceeds.

```
$('.mycheckbox').click(function(){
 var count =   $("input:checked").length;
}
```

Note: Please add a classname property to all the checkboxes with same class name.